# Android Parse multiple JSON arrays

Tags: android, json, parsing

I tried to parse multiple JSON arrays that my server returns to my application.

The structure of the returned message from the server looks like this:

> [ json objects ][ json objects ]

returned message :

> [{"latitude":"44.33","longitude":"44.33","name":"test1","Notification":"true"}][{"latitude":"44.33","longitude":"44.33","name":"test2","Notification":"false"}]

Now I tried to parse this and get the Notification status (true / false) but I did not get the item i needed.

```
  try {

       JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(answer);
       JSONObject jb = (JSONObject)jr.getJSONObject(0);
       JSONArray nof = jb.getJSONArray("Notification");
       Log.d("Json", String.valueOf(nof));
  }catch(Exception e)
  {
       e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

I would be happy if someone can help me to understand what I need todo to achieve my mission.

Comment: You can rather use GSON for parsing, it is much easier. Use GsonFormatter Android studio plug-in for creating model classes

Comment: what is answer in your first line? and do you get any error?

Comment: Yes  I get the next error - " Value true at Notification of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray "

Comment: Your return message is not a valid JSON. Try wrapping those arrays in an array with a key. Like this: https://hastebin.com/amohisened.json

Comment: You should use  `String nof = jb.getString("Notification");` instead of  `JSONArray nof = jb.getJSONArray("Notification");` and to print you can simply print value of nof like `Log.d("Json", nof);`

Comment: @Prashant  Thanks it's work but now how I can pass between the arrays ? Thanks you are the kink !

Comment: @asaproG Please post full response first

Answer (score 2):

Your Json response is invalid...

This is the valid JSON:

```
  [
    [{
        "latitude": "44.33",
        "longitude": "44.33",
        "name": "test1",
        "Notification": "true"
    }],
    [{
        "latitude": "44.33",
        "longitude": "44.33",
        "name": "test2",
        "Notification": "false"
    }]
  ]
```

to parse it:

```
try{
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(answer);
for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++){
     JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray(i);
         for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
            JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
            String Notification = object.getString("Notification");

        }
    }
 }
 catch (JSONException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: he is getting error when trying to get value of `Notification` , exception should be something else if it is invalid json. i thinks it's mistake in posting question , see comments in question

Comment: that why i said...it is not a valid JSON

Comment: I try this but in the line " JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray(i); " I get the error - " Value at 0 of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray "

Comment: okay in your response u r getting ,,a JSON object...post the full response...the response u posted on question is wrong!

Comment: The problem is the size of the array when I check him is 1 and it need to be 2 ( json.length() ) so in your code it's get only the first element and that make the problem. how I get all the elements of the array ?

Comment: you need to modify your JSON response to wrap the `[whrole response]`  ... then you can get a array of dynamic elements..then my code will work

Answer (score 0):

That Json response can't be parsed as a whole. Formally it is not json valid, there are two json arrays that concatenate like that do not make a valid json.

You can wrap those array in a unique json object and that object is now parsable with your code.

```
{"array1":[],"array2":[]}
```

Then you can instantiate the jsonObject and get each array separately with their name

Comment: Thanks, but how I can convert my correct return string to the type like you answer ?

Comment: It depends on the language you are using on the server side to generate that json

Answer (score 0):

Create a POJO of Response lets say Notification.java

```
JSONArray resultArray = response.getJSONArray("result");// your json response
```

// using Gson Library By google

compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7.0'

```
List<Notification> notificationList = new    Gson().fromJson(String.valueOf(resultArray),Notification.class);
```